# Showing method has same convergence as Newton's?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am using the following method to compute the solution to a nonlinear equation. Start by computing the value from Newton's method: $\hat x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$ and then use it to compute the next iteration $x_{k+1} = \frac{x_k + \hat x_{k+1}}{2}$. I want to show that this method converges under the same condition's as newton's method but I am not sure how to do that. Would showing how an $f(x) = 0$ that converges for Newton's method also work for this method?

Comment: What are these  conditions for Newton's method that you want to use? You are reducing quadratic to linear convergence, thus also called dampened Newton method, so it will not have "the same convergence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can think about Newton's method mapping a rootfinding problem in $f$ to a fixed point problem in $g$. We do this by letting $g(x) := x - f(x)/f^{\prime}(x)$.

To analyze the convergence behavior of Newton, it's convenient to consider $g^{\prime}$. We are led to think about this because $f(x) = x \implies g^{\prime}(x) = 0$. In this case, if $g^{\prime}(x) = 0$, then we'll have second order convergence (due to Taylor: consider $g(y) - x = 0 + \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^2 g^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$ for $\xi \in (x,y)$). Thus the error is like $e_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}(e_k)^2 g^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$. Below we'll try and get something similar for your method.

Here's a start: consider the new fixed point function $\tilde{g}(x) = \frac{x + x - f(x)/f^{\prime}(x)}{2}$. This boils down to
$$
\tilde{g}(x) = x - \frac{1}{2} \frac{f(x)}{f^{\prime}(x)}.
$$

We can see this iteratively with

$$
x_{k+1} = \tilde{g}(x_{k}) = \frac{x_{k} + x_k - \frac{f(x_k}{f^{\prime}(x_k)}}{2} = x_k - \frac{1}{2}\frac{f(x_k)}{f^{\prime}(x_k)}.
$$

Now what can we say about the error $|\tilde{g}(x_{k}) - x|$ if $|g(x_k) - x|$ converges?

Comment: Would it be that the error $|\tilde{g}(x_{k}) - x|$ goes to 0 if $|g(x_k) - x|$ converges?